# How to find objects with specific properties(another objects with specific properties) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, object, oop, properties

For example, an object 'student' with a property 'test' , and 'test' is also an object with a property 'score'.

```
classdef student < handle

    properties
        name
        test
    end

    methods


        function obj = student(name)
            obj.name = name;
            obj.test = test();
        end
    end
end
```

```
classdef test < handle

    properties
        content
        score
    end
end
```

```
student_arr=[student('A') student('B')]
student_arr(1).test.score=100
student_arr(2).test.score=80
```

I want to find students whose score of test is 100. I use function findobj

```
findobj([student_arr.test],'score',100)

ans = 

  test with properties:

    content: []
      score: 100
```

It return a test array, not a student array.

But if I try to find it in the student_arr

```
findobj(student_arr,'score',100)

ans = 

  0×0 student array with properties:

    name
    test
```

It return a 0*0 student array, because 'score' is not a property of student.

The question is, if an object's property is another object, how to find the former based on properties of latter?

Comment: Please edit your question to add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have added one.

Comment: Your second example doesn't work because you try to compare strings with `==` where you should use [`strcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! `G = findobj (student_arr, '-function', @(x) x.test.score == 100 && strcmp(x.test.content,'maths'))`

Comment: Please don’t add questions to your post. You received an answer, if you have further questions, make a new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit undocumented, but you can use `findobj` with an additionnal `function` to specify the search:

```
H = findobj (student_arr, '-function', @(x) x.test.score == 100 );
```

Comment: Thank you! So I have to use function handle, no orther simpler methods?

Comment: Well this is already pretty simple, isn't it?

Comment: Well, but it doesn't seem to be fit for complex case. For example, how to find objects based on severial properties? I have added anthor example.

Comment: This is a different question, and should be asked separately